# Pass parameters to get JSON Array in Volley library using StringRequest?

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I wanted to fire custom query in sql by passing a parameter to server and get JSON array. I'm using Volley library to handle html requests. But, with the following code my application freezes. I've searched though internet but I'm not able to recover it. Here's the code:

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.serv_url, /*url to server*/ new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                int count = 0;
                while(count<response.length()) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                                arrayList.add(new Album(jsonObject.getString("id")));
                        count++;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter = new customImagesSwipe(arrayList,DisplayActivity.this);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Error :- " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        // here is params will add to your url using post method
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("num", image); //value for param
            //params.put("2ndParamName","valueoF2ndParam");
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getMinstance(DisplayActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Here's the php script:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "imagesfromserver";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user_name,$password,$db_name);

$num = $_POST["num"];
$sql = "select * from album_info where (lower(id) LIKE 'num%');";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row["id"],"title"=>$row["title"]));
}

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I have no prior knowledge of working in client server. I'm implementing from searching from Internet.

Update:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.serv_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            int count = 0;
            while(count<response.length()){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                    arrayList.add(new Album(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("title")));
                    count++;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            adapter = new customImagesSwipe(arrayList,DisplayActivity.this);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,"NULL\n" + error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getMinstance(DisplayActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: make sure that service is working fine using any rest client like postman or advance rest client

Comment: The server works jist fine. When I do not pass parameter, I can get whole json array. But, not with this

Comment: are u sure that server is returning json array as string response

Comment: As I told you, when I retrieve everything from database (select * from album_info). It gives JSON array.

Comment: i saw that u r using StringRequest  for fetching data from server, which expects response as String, if response is josn then u can using JsonArrayRequest

Comment: check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: But I used JsonArrayRequest to get whole data.. Did not tried with StringRequest

Comment: I have given code I used for retrieving whole data using JsonArrayRequest

Comment: It says value of  String cannot be converted into jsonArray

Comment: okey, then u r right. its  string request

Comment: is there any error u r getting? the code looks ok

Comment: Yes I'm getting java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Comment: No, when u are using string request is there any error

Comment: No, the application freezes. It does not do anything

Comment: Please post complete code examples. This means that the code you posted here must be in a method in a class.

Comment: try this url http://api.androidhive.info/volley/string_response.html for testing and freeze the code inside onResponse.jsut log the response and on error

Comment: app always freezing with StringRequest

Comment: then it may be related to code something other than the network request part, try calling this service in a test activity with a button click

Comment: That's what I was thinking of. It should be in code that causing problem. You can try my code so that you find the problem.

Comment: There was a mistake in php script. the variable &num was in the double quote ("_"). Now code works fine with StringRequest.